# align circle in a table with text

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to align my custom circle with the text. i tried vertical align and still cant get it to look right. here is my code, css then html. I am putting it in a table with three circles in each.

http://jsfiddle.net/o7cmvv28/

```
   .circle_table{
   background-color: #F9FBFF;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #293041;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 6px gray;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.circle{
width:75px;
height:75px;
border-radius: 50%;
}


  .circle_table
      %table.table.borderless
      %tbody
        %tr
          %td
            .circle_dark_green
          %td
            \#green
```

Comment: Can you create demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o7cmvv28/

Comment: it will have 3 circles in each row

Comment: How you want to align text to the circle? middle, top, bottom?\

Comment: alignt the text to the middle of the circle